# Refresh custom Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS newbie here and would like to get help on the above please.

Basically my app has a directive that loads banner data from an API and applies the flexslider plugin to render the slideshow.

What I'd like to achieve is to refresh or re-trigger this directive when the URL changes, which also re-triggers the flexslider. Apologies for the lack of a better term. The reason is different banners should be displayed on different pages and I'm adjusting the API call accordingly.

Any thoughts on how I might solve the above problem?

Appreciate all the help, thanks!

Here are the code snippets:

**index.html**

```
<div id="hero" class="wrapper">
      <hero-container></hero-container>
    </div>
```

**herocontainer.js directive**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name loadandgoApp.directive:heroContainer
 * @description
 * # heroContainer
 */
angular.module('loadandgoApp')
  .directive('heroContainer', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
      template: '<div class="flexslider"><div class="slides"><div hero-item class="slide" ng-repeat="item in headerContent"></div></div></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function($scope, ContentService) {
        $scope.headerContent = [];
        ContentService.loadHeaders.then(function(data) {
          $scope.headerContent = data;
        });
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('headerContent', function (val) {
          if (val.length) {
            $timeout(function() {
              angular.element(element).children('.flexslider').flexslider({
                selector: '.slides > .slide',
                start: function() {
                  $('.flexslider').show();
                },
              });
            }, 400);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }])
;
```

Comment: `scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function doSomething() { ... })`

Comment: Hi @Phil, will I get access to headerContent from within the callback function? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui-router - whenever you place a link that points to that page, set the reload option to true.

`<a ui-sref="(state)" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}"> </a>`

Comment: Useless make no sense !

Comment: How so? It's the only way i've been able to refresh between views

Comment: You are talking about views, and you right about this, but the question about the directive, here we have flexslider, need refresh slider after he get data, he is not talking about the views or stats.